# Retrieving keys in dictionary in same index order

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to extract keys of a dictionary as the same order in dictionary.

Let's look at the code below:

```
 let farm: [String:String] = ["a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f", "g":"h"]
    print(Array(farm.keys))  //printed result is ["e", "a", "g", "c"]
```

Is there a way to extract just keys like following?

```
[ "a", "c", "e", "g" ]
```

I need to extract the key as in same order as in the dictionary.

If there is no way to achieve this, I would like to know if I can access Dictionary with index and retrieve key-value pair on that index.

Comment: A dictionary has no order, it's an unordered collection. Even when you create a seemingly ordered dictionary like `["a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f", "g":"h"]` it is not stored in this order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge in swift dictionary are not order they only manage key-value.
for get same order either you have to save all value in array with one object(key-value) at one index or you have to pass all key in array at time you are creating dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Keys in dictionary are not sorted. But you can get and sort them this way :

```
let farm: [String:String] = ["a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f", "g":"h"]
let sortedKeys = Array(farm.keys).sort(<) //["a", "c", "e", "g"]
```